# How to call a Java function in the 'when' part of the drools rule?

Tags: java, drools, rule

I have been searching for a while now, but I can't find the exact answer to my question anywhere, or if I find something similar, it doesn't works.

I want to call a simple java method in the when part of the rule.

My code looks like this:

```
rule "Ret Rule"
when 
    Map(this["LOYAL"] == "true")
    Map(this["LOYALTYPROMORETENTION"] == "true")
    PromotionValidityPeriod(promotionName == "VIVACLUB Loyalty Promo 2013 25 percent")
    $customer: Customer( segment == "Residential" , $assets : assets )
    $o: Order( ( (DPOrderType == 17 && retentionReason == "RET") || (DPOrderType == 2 && reason == "557") ) , $ct: contractTerms == 24, $olis: orderLineItems )
    $tariff: OrderLI( part in ("DT2319", "DT2320"), actionCode not in ("Delete", "INVALID"), $parentId : parentId) from $olis
    OrderLI( part == "DT2316", nodeId == $parentId, actionCode not in ("Delete", "INVALID"), $assetId : assetId ) from $olis
    /*Asset( assetId == $assetId,
        ( (contractTerms != null && contractEndDate != null && eval(CalculationsHelper.getFullMonthDifference(new Date(), contractEndDate) < 3 ))
            || (contractTerms == null) ) ) from $assets*/
    $li : OrderLI( $newTariff : part in ("DT2319", "DT2320"), parentId == $parentnodeid, actionCode == "Add")  from $olis 
    $del : OrderLI( $oldTariff : part, parentId == $parentnodeid, actionCode == "Delete", productType == "Calling Plan")  from $olis
    eval(OrderDwrController.setTransitionCondition(fromTariff == $oldTariff, toTariff == $newTariff) == true
then
    Offer of = new Offer("DT2331", $parentId, 7);
    System.out.println($tariffOld);
    of.getOrderLineItemAttributes().add(new OrderLIAttribute("DURATION", "" + $ct));
    of.getOrderLineItemAttributes().add(new OrderLIAttribute("Discount of MRC", "25%"));
    of.getOrderLineItemAttributes().add(new OrderLIAttribute("VIVACOM TV Package", $tariff.getProductNameENU()));
    of.setProductNameENU("VIVACLUB Loyalty Promo 2013 25 percent");
    $o.addOffer(of);
    of.setLoyaltyPromo(true);
    $o.addTextForOffer(of, new Integer[]{173});
end
```

The particular line where I have a problem is the very last one in the `when` part:

```
eval(OrderDwrController.setTransitionCondition(
    fromTariff == $oldTariff, toTariff == $newTariff) == true
```

I just want to call a simple function

```
(OrderDwrController.setTransitionCondition(
    fromTariff == $oldTariff, toTariff == $newTariff))
```

like the one above mine

```
(eval(CalculationsHelper.getFullMonthDifference(
    new Date(), contractEndDate) < 3 ))
```

The function is static, returns a boolean value. I have imported the class in the beginning of the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens? Doesn't build, doesn't do what you think it should, or what?

Comment: what version of drools are you using?

Comment: I am using Drools 5. I receive a strange error... and I can see in my program, that the rule is not working. I also have a breakpoint in my method, but I don't reach it. I don't know if I am calling the function like I am supposed to...?

Comment: This is the error: [ERR 102] Line 0:-1 mismatched input '<eof>' expecting ')' in rule "Ret Rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all you didnt close the eval().

2nd if you upgrade your drools you could just write java expressions in the then section and it'll be faster than eval()

Comment: Hmm.. you are right about the missing ')'! Thanks! Now I am receiving the error: "Only a type can be imported. bg.vivacom.dp.controller.dwr.OrderDwrController resolves to a package". Any ideas?

Comment: you havent included the imports in your drl above, but have you checked to make sure that a class by that name exists?

Comment: Yes  you should check that the package is correctly spelled and it exist in the application classpath.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it already.. Is the call spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting an answer instead of just replying to you (Don't have enough reputation yet :))

Whatever you put inside an eval must evaluate to a boolean. I am not sure yours is. That could be the problem.

Hope that helps

Cheers,

Avinash